# Loading local svg file in react-native-svg-uri but it's not shown in proper position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-svg

Here is code to load SVG file in react native:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
// import Svg, { SvgUri } from "react-native-svg";
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri';
import NoBillSvg from '../../Images/svgfile/Telescope.svg';
import NoInternetSvg from "../../I"

export const NoBillFound=()=>{ 
    return(
      <View style={styles.view}>
          <SvgUri
              width="100"
              height="100"
              viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"
              svgXmlData={NoBillSvg}
          />
        <Text style={styles.text}>No Bills Found.</Text>
    </View>
    )
}
```

I am loading svg file screenshot is given but the color is not in a proper position.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?